# iOS - AudioOutputUnitStop results in app freeze and warning

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, novocaine

sometimes the execution of

```
AudioOutputUnitStop(inputUnit)
```

results in the app to be freezed for about 10/15 seconds and the following console message:

```
WARNING:   [0x3b58918c] AURemoteIO.cpp:1225: Stop: AURemoteIO::Stop: error 0x10004003 calling TerminateOwnIOThread
```

Such code is handled by the Novocaine library and in particular it occurs in the [Novocaine pause] method which I invoke to stop the execution of the playback of an audio file (https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine/blob/master/Novocaine/Novocaine.m).

Any hint is really appreciated!

Thanks,
DAN

Comment: I'm seeing something similar (not using Novocaine). Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: Not really, but I assume I was not properly using the Audio Unit Services. At the end I changed my implementation and the problem didn't occur any more

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you changed it? I'm trying to dispatch appropriately to make sure everything happens on the same thread (incidentaly thread 1) and I still see this deadlock every once in awhile.