# AUGraphStop hangs app

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm working with an AUGraph for my application and having some trouble stopping the Graph. In particular, when I reach the end of the audio file, I would like to notify a method on the main thread that calls AUGraphStop.

I've seen a similar problem with IOUnits in this thread, but no solution:

[iOS - AudioOutputUnitStop results in app freeze and warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620337/ios-audiooutputunitstop-results-in-app-freeze-and-warning)

When calling AUGraphStop via UI methods, I have no problem stopping the AUGraph immediately. However, when I call AUGraphStop from the render callback, the app hangs for a few moments and blocks user interaction. It also spits out a few warning messages to the console.

My code:

callback function:

```
static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                 UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
//working audio playback code
//test for end of file
if(actualFramesRead == 0){
   currentMgr.endOfFile = YES; //currentMgr is reference to class managing AUGraph
   [currentMgr notifyAudioFinished]; //this method calls a main thread
    }
return noErr;
}
```

Notification method:

```
-(void) notifyAudioFinished {
    NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:     AUDIO_FINISHED], @"code",nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopEverything) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

And `stopEverything` is a class method that calls AUGraphStop.

The warning/error messages in the console are as follows:

```
WARNING:   [0x3c5d718c] 1225: AURemoteIO::Stop: error 0x10004003 calling TerminateOwnIOThread
ERROR:     [0x3830000] >aurioc> 1455: AURemoteIO@0x18077a20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004002
```

My thinking here was to use performSelectorOnMainThread to actually stop the graph, since there is no hang up when I use the app UI, which runs on the main thread, to stop it. However, I think the problem might be related to launching this method from the render callback.

Any ideas, or suggestions on better practices for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I appeared to have solved the problem, though it isn't totally clear to me.

In my class that manages reading the audio file, I have it post a notification to my class that manages the audio playback when it runs out of samples:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationEndOfAudioFile
                                                    object:self userInfo:nil];
```

In my playback class, I handle the notification like this:

```
-(void) endOfAudioFileNotification: (NSNotification *) notification{
    [self stopEverything];
}
```

The `stopEverything` method calls `AUGraphStop` with no hanging. Initially, I tried this with `stopEverything` called using `performSelectorOnMainThread` and the app continued to hang and spit out those console warnings.

So although, I'm not totally sure why, stopping the Graph outside of the Render callback with a notification seems to solve my issue. If anyone would like to provide some clarification, that would be great.